# Deprecated : The each() function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls in

Tags: php, wordpress, mobile-website

The following message appears on the top of the page when viewing the website on mobile. It refers to line 186, which goes as follow:

```
while ( $activity = each( $this->element_activities[ $tag ] ) )
```

I tried replacing it by:

```
foreach($this->element_activities[ $tag ] as $activity )
```

but it made it worse.
Would anyone have a solution?

Comment: *but it made it worse* in what way - if you are getting errors, it would be useful to see them along with the code showing where `$activity` is used.